# Table column does not show proper format

Tags: php, mysql

Table column does not show proper format

```
$lookupid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `idt_target_col` WHERE `idt_resource_id`='$user_id' AND `idt_target_tbl_type`='C' AND `idt_lookup_id`!='0'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lookupid)){
    $lookupId = $row['idt_lookup_id'];
}

$a=0;

$urrole=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM idt_resource_".$user_id."_user_role");
$a=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urrole)){
    $uname[$a]=$row[$tbltypecol];
    $role[$a]=$row[$tbltypekey];    
    $a++;
}
$cn=count($uname);
$cr=count($role);

for($h=0;$h<$cn;$h++){   
    $urr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM idt_resource_".$user_id."_user WHERE $useridtbl=$uname[$h]");   
    if($urr){                   
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urr)){
            $uriid=$row[$useridtbl];
            $fnnname=$row[$names];
            $lnnname=$row[$lnname];
            $urrname=$fnnname ."&nbsp;".$lnnname;
            echo"<tr><td>".$urrname."  </td>";
        }
    } 

    $urrl=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as idt_lookup_value FROM `idt_lookup_data` WHERE `idt_lookup_id`='$lookupId' AND `idt_lookup_key`=$role[$h]");
    //echo "SELECT count(*) as idt_lookup_value FROM `idt_lookup_data` WHERE `idt_lookup_id`='$lookupId' AND `idt_lookup_key`=$role[$h]";
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($urrl);

    //echo "SELECT idt_lookup_value FROM `idt_lookup_data` WHERE `idt_lookup_id`='$lookupId' AND `idt_lookup_key`=$role[$h]";
    if($num_rows==0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urrl)) {                                                           
            echo"<td></td></tr>";                                   
        }
    } else {
    $urrl1=mysql_query("SELECT idt_lookup_value FROM `idt_lookup_data` WHERE `idt_lookup_id`='$lookupId' AND `idt_lookup_key`=$role[$h]");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urrl1)){
            $keyvalue1=$row['idt_lookup_value'];                                        
            echo"<td>".$keyvalue1."</td></tr>";                                 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: table column not show proper format any one plz help me

Comment: what is it showing, and what do you want it to show. Frankly this question is dreadful.

Comment: in first select sql statement fetch the user id and role id from user role table ..and then second sql statement fetch the user name  from user table based on the user id and third sql statement fetch the role name from role table based on role id..at that time role id not found means the html table cell is not show proper format

Comment: thank you @ Shehary now working

Comment: As OP said my suggestion worked (and I deleted the comment so putting it back) the suggestion was to remove `<tr></tr>` from the while loop. @MohanaMadheswaran you are most welcome

Comment: one more help,i want  if the role id is not found in role table means to display blank table cells

Comment: @MohanaMadheswaran which table is the role table? what's it's exact name, so have too many queries?

Answer (score 0):

$lookupId;
            $lookupid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `idt_target_col` WHERE `idt_resource_id`='$user_id' AND `idt_target_tbl_type`='C' AND `idt_lookup_id`!='0'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lookupid))
            {
                $lookupId = $row['idt_lookup_id'];
            }
            $urrole=mysql_query("select * FROM idt_resource_".$user_id."_user_role");
                $a=0;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urrole))
                {
                    $uname[$a]=$row[$tbltypecol];
                    $role[$a]=$row[$tbltypekey];
                    $a++;
                }
                $cn=count($uname);
                $cr=count($role);
            for($h=0;$h
                    $urr=mysql_query("select * FROM idt_resource_".$user_id."_user where $useridtbl=$uname[$h]");

```
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urr))
                {
                    $uriid=$row[$useridtbl];
                    $fnnname=$row[$names];
                    $lnnname=$row[$lnname];
                    $urrname=$fnnname ."&nbsp;".$lnnname;                                                                   
                }
                if($uriid==$uname[$h])
                {
                    echo"<tr><td>".$urrname."  </td>";  
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"<tr><td></td>";
                }           
                $urrl1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `idt_lookup_data` WHERE `idt_lookup_id`='$lookupId' and `idt_lookup_key`=$role[$h]");                 
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($urrl1))
                {                       
                    $key=$row['idt_lookup_key'];    
                    $keyvalue1=$row['idt_lookup_value'];                                                        
                }
                if($key==$role[$h])
                {
                echo"<td>".$keyvalue1."</td></tr>"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"<td></td></tr>";
                }                                                   
            }
```